MariaDB Database on Server, C# on PC. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: "The given key '8704' was not present in the dictionary."
I have a Server with MariaDB and i have a c# programm on my PC to get the data.
In that programm i have a MySqlCommand that works and one that does not.
For test`s i executed both at the same point in the program and changed between both.
The first one in the Screenshot works and the second one does not. I don`t know what to do... I searched for many hours.
enter image description here
The Collation of both Tables is the same. The collation of Char columns is also the same. only the Number columns are null.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I really don`t know what to do...
I figured something out.. If a table contains a number, which has no collation, the select does not work. If a select only contains columns, which have the utf8.. collation, the select works. But why? I need both to work... If i take the CharSet out of the connectionString, the error remains

SQL Server is not the same thing as mysql - please correct your tags. Also database is only for when you haven't tagged a rdbms, so remove that too please .
